# How do I make bginfo clear the existing wallpaper before applying a new one, on logon?

Tags: windows

So in a Windows environment, we use bginfo in the all-users startup folder to write out server details to the desktop.

However, different people connect with different resolutions, and we share the account we use to connect with because we lack individual accounts at present.  The different resolutions cause bginfo to write its background at a slightly different offset each time, which means the background is garbled over time.

How can we get the desktop background to be reset on logon, so that bginfo writes its new one with a clean slate?

Don't mind if this is a thing we need to add in addition to bginfo, or whether this is built into bginfo but we haven't found the option...?

Comment: If you open your .bgi file  and choose Desktops... do you have the setting to Update this wallpaper set? I believe it should recreate the new background each time with that setting.

Comment: That works - thanks!  If you post as an answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open your .bgi file and choose `Desktops` choose the setting to `Update this wallpaper set`. I believe it should recreate the new background each time with that setting.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ten years late -- but I've suffered from this problem forever and didn't stop to really dig into it until today.  The previous answer didn't help me.  The only way I could fix the "garbled" text issue (which happens because bginfo by default rewrites changes to the same [currently active] background image that it updated the last time) I had to:

- Open the .bgi file in bginfo
- Click Background
- Use the 2nd option ("Use these settings:") to specify the source image you want bginfo to start with every time it's refreshed.  (Note: you may have to choose a Wallpaper Position other than None before it will let you select an image.)

After I switched to "Use these settings:" and picked a source image, bginfo stopped garbling the login server, date/time, etc.